# Returns five words of an audio of 1 minute duration

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

I have implemented the example code of google to convert the audio into text, the audio is hosted in google cloud and has the following features: format: flac, sample rate: 16000, 320kbps, channel: mono, language: spanish. I use the following code:

```
import sys
import os
import io


os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = '/home/eparionad/Dropbox/Tesis/CredencialesApiGoogle/Tesis-59cc7659afbc.json'

speech_file = '/home/eparionad/Descargas/19-02-2018/JuninInformado/3-JuninInformado-19-02-18-13:51.flac'


def transcribe_gcs():
    """Asynchronously transcribes the audio file specified by the gcs_uri."""
    from google.cloud import speech
    from google.cloud.speech import enums
    from google.cloud.speech import types
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    gcs_uri = 'gs://audiosparareconocimiento/3-JuninInformado-19-02-18-13:51.flac'

    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='es-PE')

    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

    print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
    response = operation.result(timeout=90)

    # Each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. Iterate through
    # them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.
    for result in response.results:
        # The first alternative is the most likely one for this portion.
        print('Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
        print('Confidence: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].confidence))
# [END def_transcribe_gcs]

transcribe_gcs()
```

Comment: Nowhere in this post have you asked a question. What is your question?

Comment: Can you post the whole OperationID response body? {}. Like that you can make sure it has finished the operation. It must have a done=true flag.

Answer (score -1):

Try to increase the timeout value to get more words

Instead of:

```
response = operation.result(timeout=90)
```

Put:

```
response = operation.result(timeout=900)
```

Comment: What question, exactly, are you answering?

Comment: Because the title said that the audio returns only five words!! The question is implicit! Change your rate, please

Comment: Then let the OP clarify .  The title doesn't say "only."  And the OP hasn't shown any error messages or output. And there is no specific question asked, anywhere.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Sorry.

Comment: The recorded audio lasts one minute and is of a person telling a story. Change to the value you suggested, but just keep returning the first words of the narrative, it's as if you did not detect any narration.